# OnClick Listener with the IF function

Tags: java, android

I need to create a login password for a user in my android app. The first part compares the setPass and the confirmation pass then saves it in the db. My problem is that else is never run 
Here is my code below...

```
  savePass.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
              if(setPass.getText().toString()
!=conPass.getText().toString()){
                Log.d("login", "Checking whether passwords created ok");
                Log.d("login", "setPass: " + setPass.getText().toString());
                Log.d("login", "conPass: " +  conPass.getText().toString());
                error.setText("Passwords do not match!");
            }else{
                Log.d("login", "showing dialog 0 ");
                showDialog(0);
                Log.d("login", "Instantiating loginNew");
                Login login = new Login();

                login.setPassword(setPass.toString());
                Log.d("login", "Adding to db");
                db.addPassword(login);
                Log.d("login", "opening main login form");
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.philsoft.budget.activity_main");
                startActivity(intent);  
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Really, is this how you debug ? Log between each every statement ? Havn't you heard of something called the `Debugger` ?

Answer (score 2):

Do not compare the two string with `==` operator. Use `String.equals()` instead.

```
if(setPass.getText().toString().equals(conPass.getText().toString())){
// your necessary codes

} else {

}
```

You have to remember, `==` compares the object references, not the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
if(!setPass.getText().toString().equals( conPass.getText().toString()) ){
```

When use the `==` or `!=` with objects compares the memory reference, not the actual value. To compare the value should use the `equals()`.

Hope it helps.